# No. of onto functions. . .

Tags: combinatorics, functions

If $A=\{x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5,x_6,x_7\}, 
B=\{y_1,y_2,y_3\},$ then find the total number of onto functions  $f:A\rightarrow B$ such that there are exactly three elements $x$ in $A$ with $f(x)=y_2.$

I am unable to solve this problem.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? If the word "onto" were removed, could you solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- We are given: three elements are sent to $y_2$.
- For onto:  in addition, at least one element is sent to $y_1$ and at least one element is sent to $y_3$.
- This leaves two elements that must be sent to $y_1$ or $y_3$.

So we count the number of distinguishable orderings of the following multisets ("spoilered" because you should know what to do just from the text appearing prior to this colon):

> $ \{1, 2, 2, 2, 3, \ 1, 1\}  \quad : \quad  \frac{7!}{3!3!1!}  $
>   $ \{1, 2, 2, 2, 3, \ 1, 3\}  \quad : \quad  \frac{7!}{2!3!2!}  $
>   $ \{1, 2, 2, 2, 3, \ 3, 3\}  \quad : \quad  \frac{7!}{1!3!3!}  $
>
>  Summing the right hand column, we get $490$.

Comment: I think you want to have exactly three elements sent to $y_2$.

Comment: @user84413 :  Ah.  Misread that.  Even easier.

Comment: Thanks,  it was a great help.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

1) First count the number of ways to choose the 3 elements in the pre-image    of $y_2$.

2) Next multiply by the number of ways to choose a subset of the 4 remaining elements to be

$\;\;\;$ the pre-image of $y_1$ (keeping in mind that this subset must be nonempty and can't be all 4 of the elements).